# Date and Time change using csv column data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I have a column name Date_and_Time having thousands of data in csv shown below:

Input:

```
Date_and_Time
2021-06-02T13:00:00.000+05:30
2021-06-02T15:00:00.000+05:30
2021-06-02T19:00:00.000+05:30
2021-06-02T21:00:00.000+05:30
2021-06-02T22:00:00.000+05:30
```

I want to change in 6 columns shown below in csv file. 'New Time' change by adding 5.30 hrs. Because of this, 'New Date' also change. There is a 'Time Gap' column too. Please help in Python. Thanks.

Output:

```
Date and Time                    Old Date    Old Time   New Date     New Time    Time Gap    
2021-06-02T13:00:00.000+05:30    2021-06-02  13:00:00   2021-06-02   18:30:00    NA
2021-06-02T15:00:00.000+05:30    2021-06-02  15:00:00   2021-06-02   20:30:00    2
2021-06-02T19:00:00.000+05:30    2021-06-02  19:00:00   2021-06-03   0:30:00     4
2021-06-02T21:00:00.000+05:30    2021-06-02  21:00:00   2021-06-03   2:30:00     2
2021-06-02T22:00:00.000+05:30    2021-06-02  22:00:00   2021-06-03   3:30:00     1
```

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to show what the expected output would be for your example

Comment: As per your comment, I have edited it with Input and Output. Thanks

Comment: what is New Time supposed to represent? UTC?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FObersteiner: New Time adds 5.30 hrs in Old Time. Based on this, New Date will change. Time Gap is based on New Time.

Comment: ok I was just wondering, because your data's UTC offset is `+05:30`, meaning that those timestamps are 5:30 hours ahead of UTC ;-)

Comment: @FObersteiner: Yes, New Time based on UTC offset +05:30. I understand. New Date is related to New Time.

Comment: Note that UTC offsets (like in ISO8601 format what you have) have to be *subtracted* to get UTC, not added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create the output format from the input column the following approach might help:

```py
import pandas as pd

add_time = pd.Timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

df['OldDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_and_Time'])
df['Old Date'] = df['OldDateTime'].dt.date
df['Old Time'] = df['OldDateTime'].dt.time
df['New Date'] = (df['OldDateTime'] + add_time).dt.date
df['New Time'] = (df['OldDateTime'] + add_time).dt.time
df['Time Gap'] = (df['OldDateTime'] - df['OldDateTime'].shift(1)).dt.total_seconds() / 3600
del df['OldDateTime']

print(df)
```

Giving you:

```
                   Date_and_Time    Old Date  Old Time    New Date  New Time  Time Gap
0  2021-06-02T13:00:00.000+05:30  2021-06-02  13:00:00  2021-06-02  18:30:00       NaN
1  2021-06-02T15:00:00.000+05:30  2021-06-02  15:00:00  2021-06-02  20:30:00       2.0
2  2021-06-02T19:00:00.000+05:30  2021-06-02  19:00:00  2021-06-03  00:30:00       4.0
3  2021-06-02T21:00:00.000+05:30  2021-06-02  21:00:00  2021-06-03  02:30:00       2.0
4  2021-06-02T22:00:00.000+05:30  2021-06-02  22:00:00  2021-06-03  03:30:00       1.0
```

This works by taking the original column and first converting it into a proper `datetime` object. This can then be used to carry out calculations such as extracting just the date or time, or for adding a fixed time to. Once the calculations have been done this extra column is removed (but could be kept).

Note: The `Time Gap` can be calculated using the difference in adjacent `OldDateTime` entries as this will always be identical to if it was calculated with `add_time` added to both. i.e. the difference will not change.

If you want the `Time Gap` in seconds, remove `/ 3600` which was converting total seconds into hours (as per your example).

Comment: Thanks Martin for the code. I have small query. When I use my csv file, time gap is not coming correctly. Actually, difference between New Time is very small. Their difference in seconds. Please suggest.

Comment: 'Time Gap' is the difference of 'New Time'

Comment: Thanks Martin, but 'Time Gap' is not coming correctly. In my csv data, difference in 'New Time' in seconds.

Comment: Please update you example to show when `Time Gap` does not work - My output is identical to your expected output.  The gap could be calculated from `New Time` but mathematically it is identical to calculating it from `OldDateTime`. Adding a constant to both sides and calculating a difference will not change anything

Comment: Thankyou for the clarity martin. I have added the result of mine at last portion @Martin. Please let me know, if its possible to change values in 'Time Gap'. Thankyou

Comment: 'Time Gap' is fixed now by removing /3600. Its now showing in sec. Thanks for help.